Retrieve a Data from HealthKit
I am working on an application related to Heart Rate Variability. To complete a step, I need the data that can be found in "Heart Rate Interval Measurements" located in HealthKit by pressing on the value returned in the variability section (the specific value is SDNN). The data I would like are those in the photo. Is it possible to retrieve them using Swift? I have been trying for a week without results.
I’ve tried to extract them from the main features but it didn’t work.

Pls try the below code
import HealthKit

class HealthKitManager {
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

    func fetchHeartRateData() {
        // Check if HealthKit is available on this device
        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            print("HealthKit is not available on this device")
            return
        }

        // Request authorization to read heart rate data
        let readTypes: Set<HKSampleType> = [HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!]
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: readTypes) { (success, error) in
            if success {
                // Define the health data type we want to read
                let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
                let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
                let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: quantityType, predicate: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
                    if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
                        for sample in results {
                            print("Heart Rate: \(sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))) bpm")
                            
                            // Fetch beat-to-beat interval data
                            let beatToBeatIntervalType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!
                            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: sample)
                            let queryBeatToBeat = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: beatToBeatIntervalType, predicate: predicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
                                if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
                                    for intervalSample in results {
                                        print("Beat-to-beat Interval: \(intervalSample.quantity) seconds")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            self.healthStore.execute(queryBeatToBeat)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.healthStore.execute(query)
            } else {
                print("Error requesting authorization for heart rate data: \(error.debugDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager()
healthKitManager.fetchHeartRateData()


It keeps printing the SDNN values I had already reached. Perhaps I didn’t explain myself well, but I am interested in the 'beat interval measurements' that underlie the calculation of the SDNN value. If you try going to the Health app, in the heart rate variability section, and click 'show all data', then proceed by choosing one at random from those present. Once clicked, at the bottom of the screen with the start and end date and the value, there is 'beat interval measurements', which if you click, leads you to a list of BPM data that I am interested in for the work I am doing

updated please check it
